# Cassandra-3.7 connection from Spring boot 2.1.2/2.1.6

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

We have an application developed in spring boot and we do use cassandra. 
Our application was suing spring boot 1.4, cassandra 3.7 and JDK 1.8
Now we are tryign to upgrade spring boot to 2.1.2/2.1.6 and JDK 1.8 to Open JDK 11.0.2 and cassandra is as : 3.7
So when we are trying, we are recieving the

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed. 
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [HOSTS] Error writing)
```

Not sure what is going wrong.

Couple of pointers is:

1) Application is running fine on local on eclipse and this is issue when we are trying to start the application in server

Here is the stacktrace I see:

```
WARN 10473 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext   : Failed startup of context o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@75a118e6{application,/console,[org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory$LoaderHidingResource@1d540566],UNAVAILABLE}

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [CassandraDatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [CassandraDatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [CassandraDatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: host1:port1 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [host1:port1] Error writing))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
```

Please let me know if any more additional details needed.

Tried to changed version of Cassandra driver version, explicilty trying to logging to Cassandra

This is our CassandraConfig class where we create the cluster object.

```java
CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
cluster.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port));
cluster.setUsername(userName);
cluster.setPassword(password);
return cluster;
```

Server should start by connecting to cassandra

Comment: what port are you using? are you sure that contact points are reachable from your boot application?

Comment: Thanks for replying.. Yes, I am sure they are reachable, since I used the same contact point and port to connect directly to cassandra and queried. Now the problem seems to be different than what I undertood.. I dont think it is anything to do with dependencies from Jdk 11.0.2, it is something to do with env. So checking on the at this moment..